# Using umat in combination with BackgroundSubtractor results in stopping of receiving frames from camera

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I'm using Emgu CV and i have a program that receives frames from a wired ip camera and uses the `BackgroundSubtractor` class to substract the background.

After a while (this is random) it stops receiving frames, it can happen in 5 min or after some hours.

I have traced the problem to the `apply` method from the `BackgroundSubtractor` class.

It's called like this: `_fgDetector.Apply(smoothedFrame, forgroundMask);` both parametes are `Umats`.

When i use the same code but with **Mat** instead of Umat then the code works for days.

When using `Umat` is see in the Visual Studio diagnostigcs that the CPU usage is ver low, this is expected due to the offloading to the GPU. When using `Mat` i see that the CPU usage is much higher which is also expected.

Can anyone explain/help with this issue? Can this be a bug in Emgu/OpenCv?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the videocard with a better model, it was a Readeon HD5450 and now it's running a ATI R920x.

The older card had 1 gb of memory and the newer one has much more, it's also a lot faster. The program is now running for about 3 weeks with no problems so far.

The older one had "hypermemory" support which used normal system ram to expent ot's memory. Maybe this caused the problem.

In short: with the better videocard there is no problem so far.